# no matches for kind "KafkaConnect" in version "kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2"

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, strimzi

I'm trying work with Strimzi to create kafka-connect cluster and encountering the following error

```
unable to recognize "kafka-connect.yaml": no matches for kind "KafkaConnect" in 
version "kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2"
```

Here's the kafka-connect.yaml I have:

```
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: KafkaConnect
metadata:
 name: kafka-connect
 namespace: connect
 annotations:
   strimzi.io/use-connector-resources: "true"
spec:
 version: 2.4.0
 replicas: 1
 bootstrapServers: host:port
 tls:
   trustedCertificates:
     - secretName: connectorsecret
       certificate: cert
 config:
   group.id: o
   offset.storage.topic: strimzi-connect-cluster-offsets
   config.storage.topic: strimzi-connect-cluster-configs
   status.storage.topic: strimzi-connect-cluster-status
   sasl.mechanism: scram-sha-256
   security.protocol: SASL_SSL
   secretName: connectorsecret
   sasl.jaas.config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=username password=password
```

Then I tried to apply the config via `kubectl apply -f kafka-connect.yaml`

Is there anything necessities to create resources using Strimzi or something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two possibilities:

1. You did not installed the CRD resources
2. You are using Strimzi version which is too old and does not support the `v1beta2` API

Judging that you are trying to use Kafka 2.4.0, I guess the second option is more likely. If you ŕeally want to do that, you should make sure to use the documentation, examples and everything from the version of Strimzi you use- they should be useing one of the older APIs (`v1alpha1` or `v1beta1`).

But in general, I would **strongly** recommend you to use the latest version of Strimzi and not a version which is several years old.

---

One more note: If you want to configure the SASL authentication for your Kafka Connect cluster, you should do it in the `.spec.authentication` section of the custom resource and not in `.spec.config`.